Adding elapsed time in seconds to an approximate date in Excel over multiple datasets in a single sheet
I am not super great at Excel, have never ventured into VBA, don't know how to do macros, and have very, very limited programming knowledge, so please excuse my ignorance. I have a bunch of data in multiple csv files where a readout records a temperature measurement every however-many-seconds-ish and the number of seconds elapsed at the moment the measurement is taken from the moment the "Record data" button was pushed. I have written down the dates I started each data collection.
I can get all the data into Excel, and I can convert the seconds elapsed column into the [hh]:mm elapsed time format, but I am struggling to figure out how to write a formula that will accomplish what I want it to without having to manually go through many thousands of data points. I have added a third column to the spreadsheet, for the date. I put in the starting date, and I would like to be able to have that column auto-populate with an approximation of the date (so, if I started the recording on 6/18/2023, I would like to write that down in the top of the date column and then after 24 hours have elapsed, I would like it to then read 6/19/2023 in the date column instead). It would be particularly fantastic if it could manage that even with interrupted data collections. For instance, there were a few times when I stopped the recording, then started it again a few minutes later, and those csv files have the word "end" when the recording is stopped, and then the elapsed time in seconds starts over from 0 once the recording is started again. The text in the rows and the restarting of the total elapsed time are both giving me trouble. I have been banging my head against this all day and my brain is fried so please excuse me if I haven't explained it well.
I have put in an approximation of what I've got currently in my spreadsheet. The time column is in seconds.



t(C)
Time
[hh]:mm
Date




23.437
549.1
00:09
6/18/2023


23.44
1122.22
00:18



23.443
1695.34
00:28



23.446
2268.46
00:37



[ManyRowsLater]





23.773
3861602
1072:40



end





t(C)
Time




23.557
549.1
00:09



23.365
1122.22
00:18




I have tried converting the elapsed seconds into elapsed minutes (with the thought that I could convert that into elapsed days), and have tried to figure out from there how to add the elapsed minutes in from the previous session when a new data recording session starts, but haven't been able to figure out how to do that between sessions, and have not been able to figure out if it is even possible to add elapsed days onto the date smartly (so if my elapsed days column reads [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2] I only want it to add to the date when it changes from 0 to 1 and then again when it changes from 1 to 2). I have tried many different IFs and nested IFs and NOTs and ISNUMBER(SEARCH)es with ANDs and ORs and have thoroughly exhausted my limited Excel knowledge and have searched many other people's questions here about adding elapsed time.
Please let me know if you need any additional details or further explanations. Thank you!
